# Orbot was fine but now perpetually stuck on "Orbot is starting"

Tags: orbot

I have been using Tor (Orbot app) for quite some time now on my old Android phone (Galaxy S4) and until recently (last week or two) it was working just fine. Now, it does not connect.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the app several times. When I originally downloaded it (maybe a year or two ago?) I didn't do anything special for it to work. It connected quickly and I could see the relays (wherever it was bouncing around to).

Does anyone have any suggestions about what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Bitsy, I am having the very same problem as you. I am looking for advice on a fix, but no luck yet. If you figure it out, please pass it along!

Comment: your best bet is probably to contact the Guardian Project by email or IRC to get support: https://dev.guardianproject.info

Comment: Same stuck on orbit is staring for now 2 days, i have uninstalled and installed back again, looks like it's solved the issue... dont know what happened...
Btw someone know where to find log of the application?